# Also select second to last mysql value

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select the max mileage and the second biggest mileage from a table.

my query so far is:

```
SELECT oil.empid, oil.mileage, users.name, oil.date, MAX(oil.mileage)
FROM oil, users
WHERE oil.empid = users.empid
GROUP BY oil.empid
ORDER BY oil.mileage
```

but this selects the first mileage entered and the max.

how do i change this to get the second biggest mileage?

Comment: If u do need only the second biggest mileage, check my query..

Comment: FYI, I edited this question to remove the perl code and tags, because it is irrelevant to the core of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
IF U need only the second last mileage then use this::

```
SELECT oil.empid, oil.mileage, users.name, oil.date, MAX(oil.mileage)
FROM oil, users
WHERE oil.empid = users.empid
GROUP BY oil.empid
ORDER BY oil.mileage desc
limit 1, 1
```

If u need both the max as well as the second last use this::

```
SELECT oil.empid, oil.mileage, users.name, oil.date, MAX(oil.mileage)
FROM oil, users
WHERE oil.empid = users.empid
GROUP BY oil.empid
ORDER BY oil.mileage desc
limit 2
```

Comment: his question wants 2 rows, not one. Don't read half of the question just to be the first person to post.

Comment: this doesnt give me the second biggest mileage just the 1st and last mileage like i have already done.

Comment: which query? i mean 1st or 2nd?

Comment: My interpretation of the question is that he wants the max and second biggest, he never says anything about two rows. Therefore, the `LIMIT 1,1` will still work because it also returns the `MAX` in the query. 1 row, 2 values.

Answer (score 1):

Basically do a normal query and sort it descending and limit it by 2. Something like the below (not tested)

```
SELECT
    oil.empid,
    oil.mileage,
    users.name,
    oil.date
FROM oil, users
WHERE (oil.empid = users.empid)
GROUP BY oil.empid
ORDER BY oil.mileage DESC
LIMIT 2
```

Comment: @SashiKant read the questions. He wants 2 rows. The max and the second largest.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirt way to do it is to sort

```
ORDER BY oil.mileage DESC
```

and then

```
LIMIT 0, 2
```

Comment: But he accidentally left out the DESC in his example.